# WordPress 4.6.1 404 handling

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a challenge where you guys might help. I do have an REST interface from where get some JSON data to fill the necessary post / page data like headlines, copy and so on. On the other hand there's WordPress handling 404's on URIs that do not exists. So lets face the following scenario.

User requests the URI *www.webpage.com/im-not-there/* and because that post / page doesn't exist it send you to the `404.php` template. So far. so good, but this is where it becomes tricky.
Before I want WP to send the 404 I want to query the REST interface, asking it if the page exist (sure it's a bit more complicated as this ;)  ). So possible answers from the REST interface could be `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
On `TRUE` I want to let WP go where it belongs, but on `FALSE` I want to "put" my data into the WP file. For that I do have the proper code and use the right hooks.
There might be the case that the post / page doesn't exist so the output (404) is correct.

Easier explanation:

- User requests URI -> page / post exists -> requested template and WP stuff
- User requests URI -> page / post doesn't exist -> ask REST interface and it returns

  - -> `TRUE` -> tell WP "don't use `404.php` but use `template-xy.php`" and do your stuff as you're used to
- -> `FALSE` -> standard WP behaviour.

Found out the following:

- WP codex says cleary: "*Loading a different template is not a good use of this action hook*". The referenced hook is '`template_redirect`'
- Using `template_include` - see the codex example - causes further errors like the page is properly loaded but `<title>` is still from `404.php` template

  - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include
  - Sure I can re-add all the neccessary filters like `option_template` and `option_stylesheet` and so on but is this really the way?
- Codex says to the "wp" hook the following: "*This hook is one effective place to perform any high-level filtering or validation, following queries, but before WordPress does any routing, processing, or handling. [...]*"

  - From this point I'm not getting any further.

Further reading:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/handle_404/

**Setup**

- Vagrant & PuPHPet
- Nginx
- MySQL 5.6
- PHP 5.6
- WordPress 4.6.1
- No Plugins activated
- Pretty URLs

**Restrictions:**

- no core overrides
- can't use server-side handling
- using a filter on `template_include` is too late and causes further "errors" e.g. `<title>`

Sorry for not posting all codex links but Stackoverflow won't let me. :)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I missed one but important step!

To set the HTTP header from 404 to 200 and also tell WP hat everything wen'T well.

So to use the codex example this is the solution on a 404

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );

function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {
  global $wp_query;

  if ( $wp_query->is_404 ) { // TRUE
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'no-404-template.php' ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
        if ($wp_query->is_404) {
            $wp_query->is_404 = FALSE;
            $wp_query->is_archive = TRUE;
        }
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

        return $new_template ;
    }
  }

  return $template;
}
```